# Javascript Array.push isn't working in get method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a range property on a sequence object with the following code:

```
function RangeSeq(from, to) {
  this.array = [];
  this.from = from;
  this.to = to;
  this.arraySeq = new ArraySeq(this.range);
}

Object.defineProperty(RangeSeq.prototype, "range", {
  get: function() {
    for (var i = this.from; i <= this.to; i++) {
      array.push[i];
      console.log(this.array)
    } 
    return array;
  }
});
```

However, after running the code above, the array object still remains empty. Why is this so and what's the right way to solve this?

Comment: `this.array` not just `array`

Comment: @Pointy thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

You used square brackets and not referring to `this.array`. It should be

```
this.array.push(i);
```

Comment: also it has to be `this.array`

Comment: @Pointy updated the answer to contain this also, thank you :)